# Count condition met

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (stu_grades) that stores student data and their grades at the centers they attended

I want to find out how many times for e.g. each student in that table got 'A' and then 'B' etc at any center

stu_grades

```
 stu_ID|grade1|grade2|Grade3|center
    1        A      A     C    1
    2        B      B     B    2
    3        C      C     A    1
    1        C      A     C    2
```

the same student could occur more than once in the table with the same grades or even a different grade, same or different center

I especially want to check where the grade has appeared more than 3 or more times and how many centeres they exist in

So the final output should be like:

```
Stu_ID|Grade|Count|centercount
1       A      3       2 (As they accquired 'A' from 2 centres)
1       C      3       2 
2       B      3       1 (As they only exist in 1 centre)
3       C      2       1 
3       A      1       1
```

Comment: Why 3 different grade columns?

Comment: @jarlh 3 different subjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    stu_id, 
    grade, 
    sum(count) count, 
    count(distinct center) centercount
from (
    select stu_id, grade, center, count(*)
    from stu_grades,
    lateral unnest(array[grade1, grade2, grade3]) grade
    group by 1, 2, 3
    ) s
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;
```

[Test it here.](http://rextester.com/WKNW81129)